# How to create a new text file using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm practicing the management of .txt files in python. I've been reading about it and found that if I try to open a file that doesn't exists yet it will create it on the same directory from where the program is being executed. The problem comes that when I try to open it, I get this error:

> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   'C:\Users\myusername\PycharmProjects\Tests\copy.txt'.

I even tried specifying a path as you can see in the error.

```
import os
THIS_FOLDER = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
my_file = os.path.join(THIS_FOLDER, 'copy.txt')
```

Comment: We cannot tell you what error you have in your code if you don't show us your code.

Comment: @JohnAnderson done.

Comment: @JustHalf This code doesn't raise an error when I run it in PyCharm?

Comment: That code doesn't open a file, it just creates a path object.

Comment: The IDE you're using is irrelevant here. It does not affect the behavior of Python code that you run from it.

Comment: This code works on my computer if I substitute a filename for `__file__`.  It produces a string.  `'/Users/myusername/copy.txt'` in my case

Comment: His problem is not about the code he shows (where he gets the path of the file), the problem it is about opening the file, where he gets an error.

Answer (score 188, accepted):

Looks like you forgot the mode parameter when calling `open`, try `w`:

```
with open("copy.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write("Your text goes here")
```

The default value is `r` and will fail if the file does not exist

```
'r' open for reading (default)
'w' open for writing, truncating the file first
```

Other interesting options are

```
'x' open for exclusive creation, failing if the file already exists
'a' open for writing, appending to the end of the file if it exists
```

See Doc for [Python2.7](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#open) or [Python3.6](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#open)

Answer (score 15):

```
# Method 1
f = open("Path/To/Your/File.txt", "w")   # 'r' for reading and 'w' for writing
f.write("Hello World from " + f.name)    # Write inside file 
f.close()                                # Close file 

# Method 2
with open("Path/To/Your/File.txt", "w") as f:   # Opens file and casts as f 
    f.write("Hello World form " + f.name)       # Writing
    # File closed automatically
```

There are many more methods but these two are most common. Hope this helped!

Comment: To be clear, you do not need to call `f.close()` when using `with open(...)`.