# how can I save all the values in a single txt file?

Tags: python

i have this code:

```
for ts in u.trajectory:
C= u.select_atoms("resid 1-360").center_of_geometry()
print("Frame: {0:5d}, Time: {1:8.3f} ps".format(ts.frame, u.trajectory.time))
print(C)
```

it works correctly, infact i have the right output in console:

```
Frame:  1368, Time:   66.879 ps
[130.05973581 252.66481884 127.07351932]
Frame:  1369, Time:   66.928 ps
[130.06893641 252.44106886 126.9491674 ]
Frame:  1370, Time:   66.977 ps
[130.1192347  252.60012987 126.83614898]
Frame:  1371, Time:   67.026 ps
[130.18082118 252.68871264 127.0049008 ]
Frame:  1372, Time:   67.075 ps
[130.08001144 252.82253858 127.01025264]
Frame:  1373, Time:   67.124 ps
[130.08522401 252.72558336 126.90693256]
exc.. exc..
```

My question is: 
how can I save all the results in a single txt file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a new text file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48959098/how-to-create-a-new-text-file-using-python)

Comment: `open()` a file, then `write()` to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you want to save all of the values of `C` in an array of arrays. Simply do:

```
allValues = []

for ts in u.trajectory:
    C = u.select_atoms("resid 1-360").center_of_geometry()
    allValues.append([C, [ts.frame], [u.trajectory.time]])
    print("Frame: {0:5d}, Time: {1:8.3f} ps".format(ts.frame, u.trajectory.time))
    print(C)
```

Next, you can save `allValues` to a text file simply using:

```
arrayOfItems = [",".join(str(item)) for item in allValues]
arrayOfStrings = [";".join(cell) for cell in arrayOfItems] # Convert each value to a string

file = open("save.txt","w+")
for row in allValues:
    file.write(line)
```

To read the contents of the file back into an array, do:

```
allValues = []

with open("save.txt") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        thisLine = line.split(";")
        thisInfo = [thisSection.split(",") for thisSection in thisLine]
        allValues.append([float(thisCol) for thisCol in thisInfo])
```

Comment: in save.txt there is:
 this Frame:  5000, Time:  244.441 psFrame:  5000, Time:  244.441 psFrame:  5000, Time:  244.441 psFrame:  5000, Time:  244.441 psFrame:  5000, Time:  244.441 psFrame:  5000, Time:  244.441 psFrame:  5000, Time:  244.441 psFrame:  5000, Time:  244.441 psFrame:  5000, Time:  244.441 psFrame:  5000, Time:  244.441 psFrame:  5000, Time:  244.441 psFrame:  5000, Time:  244.441 psFrame:  5000, Time:  244.441 psFrame:  5000, Time:  244.441 psFrame:  5000, Time:  244.441 psFrame:  5000, Time:  244.441 psFrame:  5000, Time:  244.441. 
thanks

Comment: @PietroDelre Try now.

Comment: @PietroDelre I'd appreciate if you could mark this as the answer, because it seems mine is the only one which actually talks about how to get the numbers back out again.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sample code

```
with open('output.txt', 'w+') as opfile:
    for ts in u.trajectory:
       C= u.select_atoms("resid 1-360").center_of_geometry()
       opfile.write("Frame: {0:5d}, Time: {1:8.3f} ps\n".format(ts.frame, u.trajectory.time))
       opfile.write(str(C)+'\n')
```

Comment: in txt file there are always the same value: 
Frame:     0, Time:    0.000 ps
[[  0.         128.86617802 251.8184559 ]
 [128.86617802   0.         125.58342006]
 [251.8184559  125.58342006   0.        ]]
[...]
Frame:  1373, Time:   67.124 ps
[[  0.         128.86617802 251.8184559 ]
 [128.86617802   0.         125.58342006]
 [251.8184559  125.58342006   0.        ]]

Comment: I think I used the wrong variable name ```c``` instead of ```C```, fixed it

Answer (score 0):

You could append all of that data into a list then write it into a text file this way.

```
tempList = []
for ts in u.trajectory:
    C= u.select_atoms("resid 1-360").center_of_geometry()
    tempList.append("Frame: {0:5d}, Time: {1:8.3f} ps".format(ts.frame, u.trajectory.time))
    tempList.append(C)


f= open("sample.txt","w+")
for line in tempList:
    f.write(line)
```

Comment: thanks, but with this code added i have an empty txt